# how do I set the command time out in the new ormlite api

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I upgraded to the new version of ormlite and am updating my code but do not see where I can set the commandtime out now that every thing is off of idbconnection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353719/servicestack-ormlite-command-timeout

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in the other thread, I created an extension method to handle this scenario and still keep the nice API:

```
public static partial class IDbConnectionExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<T> Query<T>(this IDbConnection self, string sql, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
    {
        List<T> results = null;
        self.Exec((dbCmd) =>
            {
                dbCmd.CommandTimeout = (int)commandTimeout.TotalSeconds;
                dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
                using (var reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    results = reader.ConvertToList<T>();
                }
            });

        return results;
    }   // eo Query<T>
}   // eo class IDbConnectionExtensionMethods
```