# ServiceStack OrmLite Command Timeout

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

When using IDbConnection.ExecuteSql how do I set the Command Timeout?

```
IDbConnection db = ConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection();
db.ExecuteSql("...");
```

If I use the IDbCommand.ExecuteSql ( See below ) method I can set the Command Timeout, but I get a bunch of warnings about deprecated methods.

```
IDbCommand comm = db.CreateCommand()
comm.CommandTimeout = 240;                    
comm.ExecuteSql("...");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the most recent change OrmLite no longer provides APIs around the `IDbCommand` object directly (which have now all been made internal in the latest version).

But since OrmLite is only extension methods over ADO.NET's underlying [IDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx) and [IDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.aspx) interfaces, you can easily by-pass OrmLite's extension methods when you need to and just use them directly, e.g:

```
IDbConnection db = ConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection();
IDbCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 240;  
cmd.CommandText = "...";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Alternatively you can set a global CommandTimeout with:

```
OrmLiteConfig.CommandTimeout = 240;
```

Comment: What if we want to use sql generated by db.Select. When we want to set timeout, we should use custom handwritten sql queries ? @mythz

Comment: @mustafasturan, having same issue...  I use `IDbConnection.Query<>` and I need to specify the timeout of *that*.

Comment: Is this still the best solution? It seems like if you set the CommandTimeout paramater on the connection string that all commands created using that dbconnection should use the supplied timeout. Is there a possiblity of this behavior being changed?

Comment: @on3al I've updated answer to include `OrmLiteConfig.CommandTimeout` example

Comment: Are there any plans to allow it to be set, non globally? I was hoping to allow consumers of an api to set it per request

Comment: @on3al this is [only other alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25911260/85785) the only plans for [new features are maintained on UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party and as you've seen in my comment, I've had this exact issue.  My solution was to extend on myth's suggestion and create a new extension method:

```
public static partial class IDbConnectionExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<T> Query<T>(this IDbConnection self, string sql, int commandTimeout)
    {
        List<T> results = null;
        self.Exec((dbCmd) =>
            {
                dbCmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
                using (var reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    results = reader.ConvertToList<T>();
                }
            });

        return results;
    }   // eo Query<T>
}   // eo class IDbConnectionExtensionMethods
```